# Merging Sync Framework 2.1 Scopes

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

I've used SqlSyncScopeProvisioning to create ScopeA ScopeB and ScopeC. Each corresponds to a single table, TableA TableB TableC. There are no filters, and all the data is syncing between the servers correctly.

I'd now like to clean up the scopes and have a single scope to cover all of the tables, instead of 3 scopes. Let's call it ScopeAll.

If I provision ScopeAll containing TableA TableB TableC, will it copy the existing knowledge data from ScopeA ScopeB ScopeC so that the initial data does not need to all be copied over and sync'd again?

After that I would then deprovision ScopeA ScopeB and ScopeC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it will not copy the sync knowledge. a scope doesn't care about any other scope in the database.

Comment: I just attempted it on a dev system and you're right, it attempts to copy everything over again. I take it this means that merging schemas is just not possible?

Comment: nope. each scope would have assigned different replica IDs. even if they were referring to the same databases, they'd be represented differently in each scope's sync knowledge.